# Create VHost & Forward subdomain to it

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu, subdomain

Gurus of So

I have a simple .htaccess file where I only redirect non www to www for my webapp. Now what I want to do is

1. Create a new vhost like http://subdomain.mydomain.tld
2. Create a redirect for anybody coming to that **subdomain** to a folder on my app like **app/webroot/subdomain**

My current .htaccess looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.tld [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.tld/$1 [R=301.L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/webroot/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

How would I go about it? Can I do this all in my .htaccess file or do I need to mess with GoDaddy as well? I rather not do this in the app, if that makes sense.

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 + Apache 2.2.14-5

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's what you need to put in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
# redirect mydomain.tld to www.mydomain.tld
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.tld [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]

# default website
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/webroot/$1 [NC,QSA,L]

# subdomain to folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(sub|subfolder)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !^www$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://www.domain.com/%1/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, Do I need to setup a vhost first for that subdomain?

Comment: You can always a vhost for it with the same DocumentRoot as the WWW if you want. You can also change the ServerAlias of your www vhost to add more domains eg: ServerAlias domain.com www.domain.com sub.domain.com.

Comment: Sorry, am a n00b with apache2. So, 2 things - 1. I want to only allow for a fixed subdomain and not ([a-z0-9]) as per your code, should I just change that to ^(sub)? 2. How do I set the vhost up again (too n00b for you? sorry)?

Comment: 1) view my updated answer. 2) Did you create a sub domain entry? Did you point it to the same place as the www?

Comment: 1) I am staring at it & can't find a single change yet, am I seriously lost? 2)No nothing else in that .htaccess file but what I have shown.

Comment: 1) refresh the page

Comment: lol, I thought I had, but it just changed, so made that edit. btw, you code should read ^www\.mydomain\.tld$ [NC] & not ^vwww\.mydomain\.tld$ [NC] (spent a minute with that :))

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3824/discussion-between-iusable-and-book-of-zeus)